# Parse Typescript types like JSON

Tags: typescript

I'm using a library to autogenerate TypeScript types from an OpenAPI JSON file. The result is a file structured like this:

```
/**
 * This file was auto-generated by openapi-typescript.
 * Do not make direct changes to the file.
 */

export interface paths {
  "/api/people": {
    /** Get data associated with person */
    get: operations["getPerson"];
  };
}

export interface components {
  schemas: {
    /** Person */
    Person: {
      /** @example Pam */
      first_name?: string;
      /** @example M */
      middle_name?: string;
      /** @example Halpert */
      last_name?: string;
      /** @example 123456789 */
      ssn?: string;
    };
  };
  responses: {
    $ref: unknown;
  };
}

export interface operations {
  /** Get data associated with person */
  getPerson: {
    parameters: {
      path: {
        /** The person's UUID */
        personUuid: string;
      };
    };
    responses: {
      200: {
        content: {
          "application/json": {
            /** Person */
            person?: {
              /** @example Pam */
              first_name?: string;
              /** @example M */
              middle_name?: string;
              /** @example Halpert */
              last_name?: string;
              /** @example 123456789 */
              ssn?: string;
            };
          };
        };
      };
      /** Unauthorized */
      401: {
        content: {
          "application/json": {
            /** @example Unauthorized */
            message: string;
          };
        };
      };
      /** Not found */
      404: {
        content: {
          "application/json": {
            /** @example Not found */
            message: string;
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}

export interface external {}
```

It has paths, components, and operations interfaces. I'm mostly/entirely interested in the operations.

Each "operation" (endpoint) has a set of responses, and I'm mostly interested in the 200 JSON of the 200 response.

If I were to get that from this types file, I'd currently do something like this:

```
import { operations } from 'typesfile';
type Response = operations['getPerson']['responses']['200']['content']['application/json'];
```

And then something like this if I wanted to be able to pass around the interface of the sub-types:

```
type Person = Response['person'];
```

That's a reasonable amount of boilerplate for each response type and the immediate sub-types, so I'm looking to generate a directory like this:

```
- types
  - index.ts
  - getPerson.ts
  ...
```

The index file would pull in and export all the collocated files, and each collocated file would represent its operation, and would ideally export both the response type and types for each subtype. So, something like this:

```
interface Person {
  /** @example Pam */
  first_name?: string;
  /** @example M */
  middle_name?: string;
  /** @example Halpert */
  last_name?: string;
  /** @example 123456789 */
  ssn?: string;
};

interface Response {
  person: Person;
}
```

Which I could then import like so:

```
import { Response, Person } from 'types/getPerson';
```

This would all be easy to do with JavaScript -- just parse the JSON, and write it to a new file -- but is there some way to do something similar with these types? Read the currently generated TS file, and then parse it and split it into files as described, with types generated from the keys of the response type? Not sure if this is possible, or how to look into it.

Comment: You can try to use the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).

Comment: What library do you use for the autogeneration? It might offer some hooks/events/customization points.